# How to change the objects of an array based on objects of another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered the following problem. I want to do the following, there is an array of 5 elements, I want to add a property and isExist to the elements of the array that are contained in the second, otherwise leave the object unchanged.

I tried to use the map method, but it returns an array of arrays to me, and I need to return the same array, only with the additional property of the first 2 objects.

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1, title:'test1'}, {id: 2, title:'test2'}, {id: 3, title:'test3'},{id: 4, title:'test4'} ,{id: 5, title:'test5'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, title:'test1'}, {id: 2, title:'test2'}];

const filteredArr = arr1.filter(item => {
    return arr2.filter(item2 => {
        if (item2.id === item.id) {
            return {...item, isExist: true}
        } else {
            return {...item}
        }
    })
})
```

Expected result: in the first array the objects with ID 1 and 2 should contain additionally the isExist property, the rest should remain in the array, but without the isExist property.

Comment: I see you've used spread notation. Do you want to create new objects? Or just add the property to the existing objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map and some

- map through `arr1` check for `id` of each element on `arr2`
- If it is found add `isExist` else return original value

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1, title:'test1'}, {id: 2, title:'test2'}, {id: 3, title:'test3'},{id: 4, title:'test4'} ,{id: 5, title:'test5'}];
const arr2 = [{id: 1, title:'test1'}, {id: 2, title:'test2'}];


let op = arr1.map(value => {
  let isExist = arr2.some(e => e.id === value.id)
  return isExist ? {...value,isExist} : value
})


console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `Set` to get all the ids on `arr2`. Use `map` to loop thru the `arr1`

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"title":"test1"},{"id":2,"title":"test2"},{"id":3,"title":"test3"},{"id":4,"title":"test4"},{"id":5,"title":"test5"}]
const arr2 = [{"id":1,"title":"test1"},{"id":2,"title":"test2"}]

const ids = new Set(arr2.map(o => o.id));
const filteredArr = arr1.map(item => {
  if (ids.has(item.id)) return { ...item,isExist: true}
  else return item;
})

console.log(filteredArr)
```

**Shorter version:**

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"title":"test1"},{"id":2,"title":"test2"},{"id":3,"title":"test3"},{"id":4,"title":"test4"},{"id":5,"title":"test5"}];
const arr2 = [{"id":1,"title":"test1"},{"id":2,"title":"test2"}];

const ids = new Set(arr2.map(o => o.id));
const filteredArr = arr1.map(item => ids.has(item.id) ? {...item,isExist: true} : item);

console.log(filteredArr)
```